# how to access Flickr API using Python?

Tags: python, api, flickr

I installed everything as it says on the [FlickrAPI homepage](http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) but when I try to run:

```
import flickrapi
api_key = '1a4c975fa83048436a2086bcab7d2290'
api_password = '5e069eae20e60297'
flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickAPI(api_key, api_password)
favourites = flickrClient.favorites_getPublicList(user_id='userid')
photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='73509078@N00', per_page='10')
sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='73509078@N00')
for photo in favourites.photos[0].photo:
print photo['title']
```

I get this message from the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Desktop>python api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "api.py", line 4, in <module>
flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickAPI(api_key, api_password)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FlickAPI'
```

Any ideas?? I have tried almost everything

Comment: Do you have another file named `flickrapi` in your python path? Does `print flickrapi.__file__` tell you anything?

Comment: i don't have another file named flickrapi in my python path. But when i type print flickrapi.__file__this message comes up: Unable to initialize device PRN

Comment: The `print` statement should be added to your python script, not your console. :-)

Comment: i tried that and it comes up with the same error

Comment: The python `print` statement outputs to your terminal / console, not your printer; the `device PRN` error points to you trying to run the `print` command in your console instead.

Comment: I import the code u told me in my script but is not working:
    import flickrapi
    api_key = '1a4c975fa83048436a2086bcab7d2290'
    api_password = '5e069eae20e60297'
    flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)
    favourites = flickrClient.favorites_getPublicList(user_id='userid')
    photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='73509078@N00', per_page='10')
    sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='73509078@N00')
    for photo in favourites.photos[0].photo:
    print photo['title']
    print flickrapi.__file__
this is my code now but with the same error

Comment: I meant you to use the statement *right after the `import` statement*, so before the error occurs.

Comment: like this?
    print flickrapi.__file__
    import flickrapi
same error

Comment: No. `import flickrapi; print flickrapi.__file__`. You'll get a print statement *before* the error. The print will not fix the error, it'll tell us more as to where the library is stored.

Comment: i tried to run it like this also:
   import flickrapi
   print flickrapi.__file__
but is not running either

Comment: maybe I did something wrong with the installations?

Answer (score 2):

`FlickAPI` is not the same as `FlickrAPI`. You're missing an `r`.

Comment: u are right amber that was a typing error i changed that also but is not working..

also i don't have another file named flickrapi in my python path. But when i type  print flickrapi.__file__ it this message comes up: Unable to initialize device PRN

Comment: Because you're typing that into a command shell rather than a Python shell.

Comment: i tried that in python shell also when I type:
    print flickrapi.__file__
    this message comes up:
    >>> print flickrapi.__file__
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'flickrapi' is not defined
and when I type:
    import flickrapi
this message comes up:
    >>> import flickrapi
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "flickrapi.py", line 4, in <module>
    flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FlickrAPI'

Answer (score 2):

The file `C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\FLICKR API\flickrapi.py` is *not* part of the `flickrapi` package. Please rename it, it is masking the real library. Right now it is being imported *instead* of the installed package.

The `flickrapi` package itself consists of a directory with a `__init__.py` file inside of it. Printing `flickrapi.__file__` *should* result in a path ending in `flickrapi\__init__.py`.

Comment: @user1832502: Then you didn't install the `flickrapi` package in the correct location.

Comment: @user1832502: Use [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to install the package with the `easy_install` command, see the [Windows notes](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#windows-notes) on that command.

Comment: @user1832502: Once `setuptools` is installed, simply run `easy_install flickrapi` and it'll be installed in the correct location for you.

Comment: the easy_install files are in the C:\\Python27\\Scripts

Comment: @user1832502: You need to run `easy_install flickrapi` on the command line. It doesn't really matter where `easy_install` *is*.

Comment: I did this before. Anyway I did it now also but the API still doesn't works

Comment: @user1832502: You did it now but `easy_install` didn't complain that the file was already installed? Did it tell you that the installation was succesful?

Comment: @user1832502: And you are certain that you are running python 2.7 when you run the `python` command?

Comment: When you run `python` in the console, it'll start the interactive python console. It'll print the version at the top. Does the version match?

Comment: @user1832502: You'd be surprised how often people have multiple Python versions installed and not know it. Okay, next step is to check `c:\python27\lib\site-packages` if there is a `flickrapi` directory there.

Comment: yes there is flickrapi files, easy_install.py, setuptools and some other files

Comment: @user1832502: and `import flickrapi; flickrapi.FlickAPI` still doesn't work?

Comment: if i type in python:
import flickrapi;
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FlickrAPI'
if i type:
import api;
NameError: name 'flickrapi' is not defined
In api.py i have the code with my api_key, api_password ...

Comment: Anyway probably there is something wrong with the paths or the installation but thank you a lot for your time

Comment: something last the setup tools must be installed in the Scripts of Python?

Comment: Alternatively, you can download the source ZIP from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flickrapi , unzip it, then run "python setup.py install" to install it.

Answer (score 0):

In your   "*flickrclient = flickrapi.FlickAPI*" line, you're missing an 'r' in FlickAPI.

Also, on the next line, your *"user_id='userid'"* argument needs an actual user ID, such as '999999@N99'

Hopefully you found that & got this working a few months ago!  :)